# Restrict generic types that extend map types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How can I restrict a generic type with an object to allow only string values? Due to I put "extends" I get a generic type that extends also to numbers and symbols.

My decision to use generics is to create subtypes and add autocompletation for an event manager that works like:

```
const listenable = new Listenable<{ 'click': () => void }>();
listenable.addEventListener( 'click', () => {} );
```

EDIT: I put the example with the error

An example that shows what I mean is:

```js
type StringMapType = {
    [ key: string ]: Function
}

class Foo< MapType extends StringMapType > {
    private callbacks: { [ key: string ]: Array< Function > } = {};

    bar< KeyType extends keyof MapType >( event: KeyType, callback: MapType[ KeyType ] ) {
        // Here the type of KeyType has to be of type `string` and
        // specifically is one of the defined MapType substrings.

        // Error due to event is string | symbol | number.
        this.callbacks[ event ] = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: [Works for me.](https://tsplay.dev/NngR6m)

Comment: @caTS no, it does not work. I updated the sample to show specifically what error causes due to is not a string.

Comment: I'd just cast it for simplicity: `this.callbacks[event as string]`

Comment: Yes, I can. Also I can define `callbacks` as any, but I had curiosity if it is a TypeScript limitation or not :/

Comment: Yep it's a limitation.